# Search function looking for multiple words

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I have a problem with a search form that searches for multiple words.

I have this function in my model. First, I search the `KeyWords` table for the foreign IDs that I need to search the library table.

This works OK when I search for one word on my `KeyWords` table but I don't know how to search for multiple words given that each of those words will return a group of ids. I don't know how to collapse them together to search in the library.

This is my search function in my library model:

```
def self.search(search)
    if search
        where("id in (?)", KeyWords.where("word like ?", "%#{search}%").pluck(:library_id))
    else
        all
    end
end
```

What I tried to do was something like spliting the search param, and, for each word in there, search the `key_words`:

```
#       array = Array.new
#       key_words = search.to_s.split(" ")
#       key_words.count.times do |i|
#           ids[i] = PalabrasClave.where("palabra like ?", "%#{key_words[i]}%").pluck(:daw_mate_acad_id)
#       end
#       where("id in (?)", ids.flatten.uniq)
```

but that does NOT work. I thought the search gave me an array of IDs that I could later collapse together with a `join` method, but sadly that does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by saying it doesn't work?  Please give some info about that, does it fail or what?

Comment: it doesn't work it doesn't bring an array of ids to be searched later in the library, brings some super random number like 15 every time you search....

Comment: i added .flatten.uniq and now it searches for all the items in the library even if i search one word.... must be something wrong with the logic i think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was calling an `array = Array.new` when I should've been initializing `ids = Array.new`:

```
ids = Array.new
       key_words = search.to_s.split(" ")
       key_words.count.times do |i|
           ids[i] = PalabrasClave.where("palabra like ?", "%#{key_words[i]}%").pluck(:daw_mate_acad_id)
       end
       where("id in (?)", ids.flatten.uniq)
```

Comment: Welcome. Please don't use exclamation marks ("!") to terminate all your sentences. That's equivalent to yelling, running around and banging pans together. Also, please take the time to use proper capitalization for "I". Stack Overflow aims to be a reference book on programming problems, so consider your question and entries to be written for a reference book.

Comment: Instead of using `Array.new`, it's idiomatic to simply use `[]` unless we need some of the special behaviors of `Array.new`.

Comment: ok, i apologize i'm new to Stack Overflow.... wont happen again, the yelling thing i mean....